# Problema com TFS e Gulp

Tags: visual-studio-2013, team-foundation-server, gulpjs

Quando eu utilizo gulp com TFS eu tenho problemas para executar os comandos do gulp: o TFS quando checkado os arquivos, ele trava as ações do gulp, não deixando ele ler os arquivos checkados pelo TFS. Minha solução é dar edit em todos os arquivos da solução. Existe alguma outra solução para trabalhar com este ambiente? Porque desta maneira perco todo o controle de versão porque sempre subo todos os arquivos do *frontend*.

Comment: Você está usando TFVC? Por que não usa o Git como repositório?

Answer (score 1):

Olá, uma alternativa para este problema é utilizar o plug-in gulp-tfs (https://github.com/heatmonkey/gulp-tfs), ele te permite dar edit e lock nos arquivos desejados. O check-in até onde sei teria que ser manual mesmo.